# How do I construct my app store app url?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to include a redirect to my app page in the app store inside my app.
But how do I know what link will my app have before I put it in the store ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've already registered your app on iTunes Connect, the app link is available no matter what stage of development your app is in. I'm looking at one of my prerelease apps in iTunes Connect, and a link is available under the "More" tab:

[image]

If I try to visit this link, it generates an error. But when the app eventually is released, the link will work.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is going to take the form of the following:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/id[identifier]
```

The identifier is a numerical identifier that can be found as the `Apple ID` when you create your application in iTunes Connect.  Click on your app, click `More`, then `About This App`.